# How to add filter sql `WHERE` CLAUSE in Bigquery stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

Table in Bigquery is partitioned by timestamp column and I have written a simple procedure which works fine.

Here it is:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE DATASET_ID.TEST(from_timestamp  timestamp, to_timestamp  timestamp)
BEGIN
  SELECT
      *
  FROM
     DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID
  WHERE
      timestamp>=from_timestamp and timestamp<=to_timestamp;
END;
```

## Now when I add more filters, Bigquery throws the error.

#### Procedure with more filter:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE DATASET_ID.TEST(from_timestamp  timestamp, to_timestamp  timestamp)
BEGIN
  SELECT
      *
  FROM
     DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID
  WHERE
      timestamp>=from_timestamp and timestamp<=to_timestamp
      and app_id="xyz";
END;
```

`Error validating procedure body (add OPTIONS(strict_mode=false) to suppress): Query error: Query error: Cannot query over table ' DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID' without a filter over column(s) 'timestamp' that can be used for partition elimination at [3:3]`

What is the best way to add more filters to where clause in stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_using_pseudo_columns), when you have a partitioned table you need to specify the partition you will query against.

In addition to that, the `CREATE PROCEDURE` has an optional flag *`[strict_mode][2]`*, which :

1. If set to **`TRUE`**:

> The procedure body will undergo additional checks for errors such as
> non-existent tables or columns. The CREATE PROCEDURE statement will
> fail if the body fails any of these checks.

2. If set to **`FALSE`**:

> The procedure body is checked only for syntax. Procedures which invoke
> themselves recursively should be created with strict_mode=FALSE to
> avoid errors caused by the procedure not yet existing while it is
> being validated

The default is set to **`TRUE`**.

I was able to replicate your case with a timestamp partitioned table, creating the procedure and adding more filters in the `WHERE` clause successfully. Below is the table I used.

```
Row _time                   dummy_column
1   2020-06-15 23:57:00 UTC a
2   2020-06-15 23:58:00 UTC b
3   2020-06-15 23:59:00 UTC c
4   2020-06-16 00:00:00 UTC d
5   2020-06-16 00:00:01 UTC e
6   2020-06-16 00:00:02 UTC f
```

The table is partitioned by the field `_time` which is a `TIMESTAMP`.

In order to create the procedure with a time range, I used the [BETWEEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators) operator. Then after storing it, I added an extra filter `dummy_column="d"`. The final procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project_id.dataset.procedure`(from_ts TIMESTAMP, to_ts TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
  select *
  from `project_id.dataset.partitioned_table` 
  where _time BETWEEN from_ts and to_ts and dummy_column="d";
END;
```

Notice that I used two filters within the *WHERE clause*. Afterwards, invoking the procedure as follows:

```
DECLARE from_ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2008-12-25 05:30:00+00");
DECLARE to_ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2020-12-25 05:30:00+00");
CALL `test-proj-261014.sample.test`(from_ts, to_ts);
```

And the output,

```
Row _time                   dummy_column    
1   2020-06-16 00:00:00 UTC d
```

As it is shown above, it ran successfully while `strict_mode=TRUE`(default) . Although, when setting it to `FALSE`, it will result in the same output without any errors. The syntax is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project_id.dataset.procedure`(from_ts TIMESTAMP, to_ts TIMESTAMP)
OPTIONS(strict_mode=FALSE)
BEGIN
  select *
  from `project_id.dataset.partitioned_table` 
  where _time BETWEEN from_ts and to_ts and dummy_column="d";
END;
```

Therefore, if you follow the instructions above you should not find any errors.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank You